# HTML: Display only one out of two datatable based on selection

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I want to display only one out of two datatables using html + js based on selection (two radio buttons).

I tried using the following code, But when i clicked on radio button nothing is happening.

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
              <input type="radio" name="table1" value="table1" onclick="handleClick(this);" checked> Quarter
              <input type="radio" name="table2" value="table2" onclick="handleClick(this);"> Month<br>              
</form>
```

JS:

```
   document.getElementById("datatable1").style.display = "";  //Show the table
    document.getElementById("datatable2").style.display = "none";  //Hide the table

function handleClick(myRadio) {
    if (myRadio.value == "table2"){
        document.getElementById("datatable1").style.display  = "none";
        document.getElementById("datatable2").style.display  = "";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("datatable1").style.display  = "";
        document.getElementById("datatable2").style.display  = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
document.getElementById("datatable1").style.display = "";  //Show the table
    document.getElementById("datatable2").style.display = "none";  //Hide the table

    function handleClick(myRadio) {
        if (myRadio.value == "table2"){
            document.getElementById("datatable1").style.display  = "none";
            document.getElementById("datatable2").style.display  = "";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("datatable1").style.display  = "";
            document.getElementById("datatable2").style.display  = "none";
        }
    }
```

```css
table{
        width: 80px;
        hight: 80px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="radio" name="table1" value="table1" onclick="handleClick(this);" checked> Quarter
    <input type="radio" name="table1" value="table2" onclick="handleClick(this);"> Month<br>
</form>

<table id="datatable1">
    <tr>
        <td>Table 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="datatable2">
    <tr>
        <td>Table 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

please change ur js as following :

```
document.getElementById("datatable1").style.display = "block" //Show the table
document.getElementById("datatable2").style.display = "none";  //Hide the table

function handleClick(myRadio) {
if (myRadio.value == "table2"){
    document.getElementById("datatable1").style.display  = "none";
    document.getElementById("datatable2").style.display  = "block" ;
}
else{
    document.getElementById("datatable1").style.display  = "block" ;
    document.getElementById("datatable2").style.display  = "none";
}
}
```